# Condense several conditional statement comparing the same value

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to know if there is a way to condense this line of code:

```
elsif i == '+' || i == '-' || i == '/' || i == '*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do

```
"+-/*".include?(i)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I originally just made a separate array and compared that earlier as a temporary solution. This works great!

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 5):

A `case when` control structure allows such a condensed line:

```
case i
when '+', '-', '/', '*'  # <= condensed line of code
  puts "operator!"
end
```

Comment: ...or `when /[-+\/*]/`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Subash but you can also do this since:

```
#this returns the match string of i which is truthy or false if no match.

elsif "+-/*"[i]
```

if you want to return a boolean true or false you can also double bang

```
elsif !!"+-/*"[i] #true if matched, false if not
```

There are many variants of this in ruby, if you had a regex or some other type of string match you might also use

```
i = '/'
!!"+-/*".match(i) #true
```